# How to know the child window is closed when we didn't have child window url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

When I open click on invite link a facebook popup is opened, I want to redirect my user to another page when that popup is closed. Here I didn't know any url which is opened in child window so I can't set listener.

So, how can i detect closing of that popup and redirect my users to another page.

I have a facebook invite script which is as follow

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
appId:'1406802056280858',
cookie:true,
status:true,
xfbml:true
});

function FacebookInviteFriends()
{
FB.ui({
method: 'apprequests',
message: 'Join me on gicree.com, the online marketplace for buyers and sellers'

});
}

if (top.location!= self.location)
{
top.location = self.location
}
</script>
```

and a html click event as follows

```
<a href='#' onclick="FacebookInviteFriends();">Invite</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [FB API Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui):

```
FB.ui(params, function(response))
```

> function(response): This specifies the function that is called
>   whenever the UI dialog is closed, either by success, cancellation, or
>   errors. The response object will depend on the dialog being used.
>   Consult the relevant dialog's own reference doc to see the response
>   object that should be returned. Defaults to null.

This callBack function is the way to go for you. You can even distinguish between the reasons, why the popup was closed!